# Make tkinter ttk checkbutton be empty when False

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I was making a simple interface with Tkinter, and noticed that when their *Checkbutton* value is False, or not clicked, it displays a black square covering the button, instead of simply being empty. Example: [image: Example]. All I wanted is to make the button completely empty when it's state is False, did a bit of digging and couldn't find it. Thanks for your time and help!

Here's the code in question:

```
querlog = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text='Quero salvar o log', command=quer_salvar_log)
querarquivo = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text='Quero salvar o arquivo de som', command=quer_salvar_som)
```

Comment: You can use onvalue and offvalue parameter go through any checkbutton widget !

Comment: @BhavyaParikh there is no need (default is 0 (offvalue) so setting it to 0 will do it), also it achieves nothing in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should associate a variable with the checkbutton, and you need to make sure the variable is set to the same value as the `offvalue` option. The `offvalue` defaults to zero. You also need to make sure to retain a reference so that the variables don't get destroyed by the garbage collector (ie: don't use local variables)

```
querlog_var = tk.StringVar(value=0)
querarquivo_var = tk.StringVar(value=0)

querlog = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text='Quero salvar o log', command=quer_salvar_log, variable=querlog_var)
querarquivo = ttk.Checkbutton(window, text='Quero salvar o arquivo de som', command=quer_salvar_som, variable=querarquivo_var)
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the same issue when not using `variable=` so here is how to do it:

```py
Checkbutton(master, variable='', **kwargs)
```

You can just set `variable` attribute as an empty string and that should fix it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry. My code is fully functional, I just want to make an aesthetic change where the button, when it's not clicked/False, instead of being filled up with black, has nothing inside it. If that's what you're saying, sorry for not understanding, and thanks for your help!

Comment: I am saying that You need to add `IntVar()` instance as value here: `variable=int_var_instance` in `Checkbutton`, wati

Comment: I edited the code to solve the issue a bit better (nothing complex)